# Is asking for learning resources on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm interested in learning a few specific aspects of game programming and I wanted some recommendations. Are "recommendation" questions off topic here?

Answer (score 4):

The Q&A site format is generally suited more towards finding answers to specific problems.

It's better to ask "How do I implement A*" instead of "Where can I find a tutorial on how to implement A*".

External resources are unreliable anyway, as links die, books go out of print, etc.

If you want to start from the ground up, there are already a ton of questions about that on the site and honestly I'd probably just close it as a dupe unless there's something specific in it that wasn't covered by other questions.

Comment: I'm really just wanting to learn about game AI and the different types and how to impliment them. I don't think that it would be practical for me to ask "How do I implement game AI?" lol. I guess I can ask in chat.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris In that case, I'd suggest either searching through the questions here for stuff you want to learn about, or asking in chat.  General questions like this would work better in the chat, anyway.